# Using COUNT(*) inside CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to use count(*) inside case statement in T-SQL?
I am trying to update records in table, but I would like to have 2 cases.

First case should do update when EndDate is less than StartDate, second case should make update only when I have exactly one record for specific EmployeeId.

```
update ep
set ep.EndDate = case when t.EndDate < t.StartDate then t.EndDate3
                 case when COUNT(*) = 1 then null
end ,ep.ModifiedBy = 'PCA', ep.ModifiedDate = getdate()
from dbo.EmployeeProductivity ep inner join cteT1 t
on ep.Id = t.Id
where t.EndDate < t.StartDate
or t.EndDate is null
```

I was trying something like this, but I get errors like:

```
an expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected
```

This is full script:

```
use ws3;

select distinct (EmployeeId) as EmployeeId
  into #Emps
  from [dbo].[EmployeeProductivity]
 where EndDate < StartDate
    or EndDate is null;

with cteProdRates as 
(
    select  ep.[ID]
           ,ep.[EmployeeId]
           ,ep.[FormatId]
           ,ep.[StartDate]
           ,ep.[EndDate]
           ,dateadd(dd, -1, lag(startdate) over (partition by ep.EmployeeId, FormatId order by StartDate desc, Id desc)) as EndDate2
           ,ep.[Rate]
      FROM [dbo].[EmployeeProductivity] ep inner join #Emps e
        on ep.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
)
,cteT1 as
(
   select [ID]
         ,[EmployeeId]
         ,[FormatId]
         ,[StartDate]
         ,[EndDate]
         ,case when EndDate2 < StartDate then StartDate else EndDate2 end as EndDate3
         ,[Rate]
    from cteProdRates
)

update ep
   set ep.EndDate = case when t.EndDate < t.StartDate then t.EndDate3
                    case when COUNT(*) = 1 then null
   end ,ep.ModifiedBy = 'PCA', ep.ModifiedDate = getdate()
  from dbo.EmployeeProductivity ep inner join cteT1 t
    on ep.Id = t.Id
 where t.EndDate < t.StartDate
    or t.EndDate is null

drop table #Emps
```

So for each unique EmployeeId I have multiple entries. Every StartDate must be greater than EndDate, and when you add new entry with new StartDate, previous entry EndDate is set to newEntry.StartDate - 1. Only if entry is the last one, EndDate is set to NULL, meaning that this entry is not closed yet.

That's why I need to check case when I have only one entry for specific EmployeeId, so I can set it to NULL.

Is this even possible to compare or do I am missing something? Anybody has an experience with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to make things clearer.

Comment: You can't perform a `COUNT` in a `SELECT` without a `GROUP BY` or `OVER` clause; it's unclear which you are after here and with no sample data or expected results we can't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: @nemo_87 Check the case syntax first , you have an extra case, should be  : case when t.EndDate < t.StartDate then t.EndDate3 when COUNT(*) = 1 then null end

Comment: @jarlh thanks for answering, I will post my whole script, maybe it will be cleaner from there and will add detail explanation too. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @ECris Thanks, this solved syntax errors, I will check if the result is correct as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `count(*)` in an `update`.  This has nothing to do with the `case` *expression*.

Perhaps this is what you intend:

```
update ep
    set ep.EndDate = (case when t.EndDate < t.StartDate then t.EndDate3
                           when cnt = 1 then null
                      end),
        ep.ModifiedBy = 'PCA',
        ep.ModifiedDate = getdate()
from dbo.EmployeeProductivity ep inner join
     (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from cteT1 t
      where t.EndDate < t.StartDate or t.EndDate is null
     ) t
     on ep.Id = t.Id
```

Of course, as the logic is phrased, the condition on the `count()` is superfluous -- the `case` *expression* returns `NULL` anyway, so this logic seems equivalent :

```
update ep
    set ep.EndDate = (case when t.EndDate < t.StartDate then t.EndDate3
                      end),
        ep.ModifiedBy = 'PCA',
        ep.ModifiedDate = getdate()
from dbo.EmployeeProductivity ep inner join
     from cteT1 t
     on ep.Id = t.Id
where t.EndDate < t.StartDate or t.EndDate is null
```

Comment: Thanks for example it's close to what I need, I will be able to make something out of it now... Still have some bad results, but I guess I need more cases to cover here @GordonLinoff